# Azure Configuration Settings More Secure than Web.Config?

Tags: asp.net, security, azure, azure-cloud-services

I'm using Azure Cloud Services, not Web Sites.

I would like to know if storing sensitive data (passwords) in Azure Service Configuration Settings is secure.

I really don't want to implement the 4-part blog series required to encrypt the web.config in Azure Web Roles, so I'm thinking I could just keep my settings in Azure config and then access them through `RoleEnvironment.GetConfigurationSettingValue()`.

These settings are in a config file much like web.config, so my question is whether this config file is just used to build the cloud service and then discarded, or if it stays on disk during the life of the instance (thereby exposing sensitive data to attack).

I like the ability to update these settings at runtime through the Portal and I consider the Portal a secure endpoint, so I'm OK with it.  However, if the file stays on disk then it is no more secure than the web.config file IMHO.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We encrypt/decrypt Azure config settings and other content using the domain certificate installed on the web roles. I posted a full example on my blog here: [Securing Azure ServiceConfiguration values for Enterprise Deployment](http://www.falconwebtech.com/post/Securing-Azure-ServiceConfiguration-values-for-Enterprise-Deployment).

Comment: thanks for posting, I did come across your blog post during my Googling but was looking to avoid this if possible.  Hopefully it helps someone else!

Answer (score 0):

I created a feature request: http://feedback.azure.com/forums/34192--general-feedback/suggestions/9025255-certificate-based-settings-encryption

This is similar (but more idiomatic, imho) to what Remote Desktop plugin does. Remote Desktop adds:

```
<ConfigurationSettings>
  <Setting name="Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Plugins.RemoteAccess.Enabled" value="true" />
  <Setting name="Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Plugins.RemoteAccess.AccountUsername" value="<name-of-user-account>" />
  <Setting name="Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Plugins.RemoteAccess.AccountEncryptedPassword" value="<base-64-encrypted-password>" />
  <Setting name="Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Plugins.RemoteAccess.AccountExpiration" value="<certificate-expiration>" />
  <Setting name="Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Plugins.RemoteForwarder.Enabled" value="true" />
</ConfigurationSettings>
<Certificates>
  <Certificate name="Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Plugins.RemoteAccess.PasswordEncryption" thumbprint="<certificate-thumbprint>" thumbprintAlgorithm="sha1" />
</Certificates>
```

RDP plugin "knows" `Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Plugins.RemoteAccess.AccountEncryptedPassword` value is encrypted will use the certificate `Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Plugins.RemoteAccess.PasswordEncryption` to decrypt it.

My feature request is to add attribute named `thumbprint` to `<Setting />` node. Calls to `CloudCloudConfigurationManager.GetSetting()` would seamlessly decrypt the value using the certificate indicated.

How wonderful that would be...